# Angular Signin doesn't work for french characters

Tags: angular

HI All I want this Signin page work for french characters as well any leads or direction will be highly appreciated.

I have tried with both utf-8 and iso in index.html but didn't work

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? Could you provide us a screenshot?

Comment: If I have understood correctly you problem, you can solve it using the encodeURIComponent() function.

Comment: I have also tried encodeUrIComponent but didn't work. special characters work but not french characters only

Comment: It's really hard to help you if you don't provide an example.